# Decoding JSON with Codable

Tags: ios, json, swift, decode, codable

I have the following `JSON` string to decode:

```
{
"albums": {
    "album": [
        {
            "name": "Dark & Wild",
            "mbid": "",
            "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/BTS",
            "artist": {
                "name": "BTS",
                "mbid": "0d79fe8e-ba27-4859-bb8c-2f255f346853",
                "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/BTS"
            },
            "image": [
                {
                    "#text": "https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/34s/6dfcd9efe7f9560334eadaf3ad6a0049.png",
                    "size": "small"
                },
                {
                    "#text": "https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/64s/6dfcd9efe7f9560334eadaf3ad6a0049.png",
                    "size": "medium"
                },
                {
                    "#text": "https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/174s/6dfcd9efe7f9560334eadaf3ad6a0049.png",
                    "size": "large"
                },
                {
                    "#text": "https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/300x300/6dfcd9efe7f9560334eadaf3ad6a0049.png",
                    "size": "extralarge"
                }
            ],
            "@attr": {
                "rank": "1"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Agust D",
            "mbid": "",
            "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Agust+D",
            "artist": {
                "name": "Agust D",
                "mbid": "",
                "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Agust+D"
            },
            "image": [
                {
                    "#text": "https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/34s/05ed3fae3b45b2fcda6c80e76c4c8aed.png",
                    "size": "small"
                },
                {
                    "#text": "https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/64s/05ed3fae3b45b2fcda6c80e76c4c8aed.png",
                    "size": "medium"
                },
                {
                    "#text": "https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/174s/05ed3fae3b45b2fcda6c80e76c4c8aed.png",
                    "size": "large"
                },
                {
                    "#text": "https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/300x300/05ed3fae3b45b2fcda6c80e76c4c8aed.png",
                    "size": "extralarge"
                }
            ],
            "@attr": {
                "rank": "2"
            }
        }
    ],
    "@attr": {
        "tag": "Hip Hop",
        "page": "1",
        "perPage": "2",
        "totalPages": "6491",
        "total": "12982"
    }
}
```

I have implemented the following `Codable` structs:

```
struct Root: Codable {
    var albums: [Album]
}

struct Album: Codable {
    var name: String
    var mbid: String
    var url: String
    var image: AlbumImage
    var artist: AlbumArtist
}

struct AlbumImage: Codable {
    var text: String
    var size: String
}

struct AlbumArtist: Codable {
    var name: String
    var mbid: String
    var url: String
}
```

Then, when I try to decode the `JSON Data` with the following function:

```
func parse(json: Data) {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    
    do {
        let root = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: json)
        print("root", root.albums)
        
    } catch {
        print("Failed to decode:", error)
    }        
}
```

The debugger throws the following error:

`Failed to decode: typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "albums", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))`

Can someone help me into fixing this issue?
Am I implementing the `Codable` structs wrongly or am I parsing it wrongly?
Thanks.

Comment: You are missing a level in your structs. The root has a property called `albums`, which leads a level with a property called `album` -- then, *that* is where the array starts. Paste your JSON into app.quicktype.io and check what it comes up with.

Comment: @jnpdx OMG, that site is amazing. I'll try the output from there.

Comment: @jnpdx Can confirm it solved my issue... I was indeed missing an extra layer, thus the error throw. Thanks for sharing it.

Comment: Your JSON tree misses one closing bracket at the end.

Comment: Your AlbumImage is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you're missing out a top property that is "Albums". Root class has single property "albums" of type dictionary and then that class contains array property as shown below:-

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let albums: Albums
}

// MARK: - Albums
struct Albums: Codable {
    let album: [Album]
    let attr: AlbumsAttr

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case album
        case attr = "@attr"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as I can see you have given type of image as AlbumImage but its expect [AlbumImage] instead of single element , try to change your model's image property  like below

var image: [AlbumImage]